# How to press TAB key to select first row in Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a form with 2 controls is textbox and datagrid.
Firstly I focus on textbox, and I want only pressing Tab Key 1 times to select first row. But now when I press Tab Key at the first time it will focus first cell but row is not seleted, when I press Tab Key at the second time first row is seleted, see the picture.

[image]

How can I press TAB key at the first time then the first row is seleted. NOT the cell selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set SelectionMode to FullRowSelect

in Form.Designer.cs     :

```
   this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

or in properties of datagridview